# How can i add a custom link field under the add to cart button?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a custom link under add to cart for each product and I'm not sure how to do this. Each of my products has a PDF file and i would like to have the option available when i edit products so I can add the link to them. I don't want to ad it in the description just under the add to cart button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button hook to place content below the add to cart button:

```
function add_content_below_cart_button(  ) { 
    // do something to add your link 
}; 


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_below_cart_button', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: will it let me add the link in the products edit page? or will it be the same link for all products?

Comment: You can use a plugin like Acf (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to add a field to your product edit page. You can then use the Acf get_field function and my code snippet above to show the link on the frontend!